# Turning a NSString into Uppercase thread breakpoint

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, runtime-error, uppercase

While trying to convert a NSString into uppercase, I get a thread breakpoint error.
I want to have the input of a question set to capital letters so that users can type in no, No, nO, and still have it be turned into NO internally.
I know I could just have it ask for a 0 or a 1, but its much more user friendly to do it this way.
I have debug mode on, which will give a little extra data to make this simpler.
I get the thread breakpoint at the [string uppercaseString] line.
For output, I get the expected debugger message the first time, but the program stops before the second one is displayed.

```
    #define DEBUG 1
    NSLog(@"Do you have an account already? YES or NO.");
    char yesOrNo [20];
    fgets (yesOrNo, sizeof yesOrNo, stdin);
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    if (yesOrNo [strlen(yesOrNo) - 1] == '\n') { //In case the input string has # characters plus \n
        yesOrNo[strlen(yesOrNo) - 1] = '\0';} //Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:yesOrNo];
    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"DEBBUGER MESSAGE: string == %@", string);
    #endif
    NSString *stringUppercase = [string uppercaseString];
    #ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"DEBBUGER MESSAGE: stringUppercase == %@", stringUppercase);
    #endif
```

Comment: Why areyou using `fgets` *and* `getchar`?

Comment: The fgets is for user input, the getchar is part of the line that flushes the stdin after each use. I got it from c-faq.com, which has been shared again and again for people like me, previously, who had problems with flushing the stdin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fgets`/`getchar` won't do what you expect - the `fgets` will read the newline after the user input, unless that input is over 19 characters, and then the `getchar` will read input until a second newline is found. Instead try:

```
if ( fscanf(stdin, "%3s", yesOrNo) == 1 )
{
   // process input
}
```

`fscanf` will *not* consume the newline - see documentation for details.

Apart from that your code works when placed in a function by itself, so if anything is stopping it from working it is coming from the context your code is in.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` probably doesn't work the way you think it does in this bit of your program:

```
if (yesOrNo [sizeof (yesOrNo) - 1] == '\n') { //In case the input string has # characters plus \n
    yesOrNo[sizeof (yesOrNo) - 1] = '\0';} //Plus '\0', the '\n' isn't added and the if condition is false
```

It's going to give you the size of the `yesOrNo` array, which is `20`, not the length of the string.  Use [`strlen(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlen/) instead:

```
if (yesOrNo[strlen(yesOrNo) - 1] ...
```

Comment: So [strlen(3) (yesOrNo)...   ?

Comment: ... no, `strlen(yesOrNo)`.  `3` is the man page section. Did you read the link?

Comment: Didn't realize you linked to something, sorry. I tried it, and it doesn't have any errors, and it will fix any problems with '\n', so thank you. However, I can't accept your answer because it doesn't answer the main problem. :/ Changed in original post.